# How can I set a memory limit for an entire docker-compose stack?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, docker-container

Besides setting a limit for each service (container) inside the docker-compose I'd love to know if there is any way to simply limit the memory the docker-compose stack has access to, similarly to the solution of every container but generalized for all the stack.

Comment: like add as global?

Comment: @EmersonPedroso yeah, like as global, (e.g. 4GB for all the three containers running in that stack)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537645/how-to-limit-docker-total-resources

Answer (score 4):

As of today, there's no "global stack" memory limit (or CPU limit) option with [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) (or [Compose Specs](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md)).

Instead, you can:

- [Limit per containers](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/deploy.md#resources) as you already suggested
- [Limit at Docker daemon level](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537645/how-to-limit-docker-total-resources) as per *@Mihal By* comment on question